# How do I get an object to spin properly in my animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes

So basically I have a sphere that is tilted over at 90 degrees, and the rotation doesn't come out clean. I hit 5 then 3, and the cursor and all that is set to center, and when I click R then 90, the end result is fine but within the animation it comes out all wonky and doesn't do a clean spin or rotation properly (I want it to simulate an orbit, without moving the space station directly above it.)

Here is the file if you wanna take a look at it. https://www.mediafire.com/?13lr815jb51ws0t

[image]

Comment: You are probably having issue with gimbal lock, but I have to dig into yoru file to find out what you did wrong. Anyway did you do the animation using local axis so you could isolate the animation only on one axis?

Comment: Try reading up on Gimbal lock on Euler rotation. Try using Quaternion rotation for your animation and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonders!

For anyone else that may be reading, a quick guide into fixing the problem can be seen in this YT video I found on the subject.
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7zncPFGYck

Comment: The link to the file is long gone, and hence can't test.  Another method would be  changing the order of the Euler rotation from 'XYZ' to say 'ZYX`  as its the order of the rotation that produces the gimbal lock.

Answer (score 1):

More reliable way of rotating the sphere on exactly the axis and degrees you want is to select it, then press X (or Y or Z depends on what axis do you want it to rotate) then type 90 (or other number of degrees you want it to rotate). Then proceed as usual with key frames and so on.
And here is what else you can do in your particular situation.
[image]

Comment: I did that but still have the same problem. :(

Comment: Cause in your example, you have to first go to first keyframe, delete all keyframes and apply rotation. Then proceed with adding rotation and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to select your sphere and rotate it to the desired angle.

Then press Shift + "S" and select "Cursor to Selected" from the drop down menu (Assuming the spheres Origin is in it's center).

Then press Shift + "A" and select "Empty" from the drop down menu.

Then select the sphere and while holding down the "SHIFT" key select the Empty. Release the "SHIFT" key And press "CTRL" + "P" and select "Object" from the drop down menu.

Now select the Empty and create your rotation animation on the Empty.